# Safari renders wrong after details element when use rem font size

Tags: html, css, safari, rendering

Safari 10.0.1 renders element following a details element wrong, when font size ist set to rem. The elements after the details rendered with font-size 1px.

**HTML**

```
<details>
  <summary>Some details</summary>
  <p>More info about the details.</p>
</details>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
html{
  font-size: 1em;
}

ul {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

If element gets rerendering (e.g. hover) element get´s repainted correct.

Is there any Workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is set the detail element to display none on default and the show it via JavaScript. Not clean but works.

Comment: You could also use Grid or Flex to change the visual order.

Answer (score 0):

Better workaround is to no use  tag at all, just use a standard  instead. This bug drove me crazy for weeks until I just found out how to easily fix it.

Seems like a big flaw in Safari, the other browsers render properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ems instead of rems?